# How to reduce the vertical spaces in the Gantt Chart?

Tags: pgfgantt

How can I reduce the vertical spaces between all the label?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{ganttchart}[
canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
include title in canvas=false,
bar label font=\small\color{black!70},
bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
bar progress label font=\footnotesize\color{black!70},
group left shift=0,
group right shift=0,
group height=.5,
group peaks tip position=0,
group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
group progress label font=\bfseries\small
  ]{1}{24}
  \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
  ]{Month:\quad1}{1}
  \gantttitlelist{2,...,24}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Work Package}{1}{24} \\
  \ganttgroup{Deliverable}{24}{24} \\
  \ganttgroup{Milestone}{5}{5} \\
  \ganttgroup{Secondment}{20}{23} \\
  \ganttgroup{Short stay}{16}{16} \\
  \ganttgroup{Training}{5}{5} \\
  \ganttgroup{Dissemination}{23}{24} \\
  \ganttgroup{Communication}{12}{12} \\
  \ganttgroup{Other}{18}{21}
 \end{ganttchart}

\end{center}
\caption{Example Gantt Chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Using `y unit chart=0.5cm,` is not of much help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add     `y unit chart= <dimension>`[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \begin{center}
            
            \begin{ganttchart}[
                y unit chart=0.5cm, % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
                hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
                vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
                title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
                title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
                title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
                include title in canvas=false,
                bar label font=\small\color{black!70},
                bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
                bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
                bar progress label font=\footnotesize\color{black!70},
                group left shift=0,
                group right shift=0,            
                group height=.5,
                group peaks tip position=0,
                group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
                group progress label font=\bfseries\small
                ]{1}{24}
                \gantttitle[
                title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
                ]{Month:\quad1}{1}
                \gantttitlelist{2,...,24}{1} \\
                \ganttgroup{Work Package}{1}{24} \\
                \ganttgroup{Deliverable}{24}{24} \\
                \ganttgroup{Milestone}{5}{5} \\
                \ganttgroup{Secondment}{20}{23} \\
                \ganttgroup{Short stay}{16}{16} \\
                \ganttgroup{Training}{5}{5} \\
                \ganttgroup{Dissemination}{23}{24} \\
                \ganttgroup{Communication}{12}{12} \\
                \ganttgroup{Other}{18}{21}
            \end{ganttchart}
            
        \end{center}
        \caption{Example Gantt Chart}
    \end{figure}    
    
\end{document}
```

To save some ink use `group height=.08,`

**UPDATED**

Also added two `\ganttmilestone`. I do not see any problem with rescaling.

The separation between the black lines will be limited by the group label font size.

[image: g]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \begin{center}
            
            \begin{ganttchart}[
                y unit chart=0.4cm, % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                y unit title=1.2cm,
                vgrid,
                hgrid,
                canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
                hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
                vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
                title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
                title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
                title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
                include title in canvas=false,
                bar label font=\small\color{black!70},
                bar label node/.append style={left=0cm},
                bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
                bar progress label font=\footnotesize\color{black!70},
                group label node/.append style={anchor=east},
                group label font = \bfseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
                milestone label font = \footnotesize\itshape,
                milestone label node/.append style={anchor=east},
                milestone height= 0.8,  %   
                group left shift=0,
                group right shift=0,            
                group height=.08,
                group label text={\footnotesize\raisebox{-2.6ex}{\smash{\strut#1}}}, %vertical correction
                group peaks tip position=0,
                group peaks height=.35,
                group peaks width = .15,
                group label node/.append style={left=.2cm},
                group progress label font=\bfseries\small
                ]{1}{24}
                \gantttitle[
                title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
                ]{Month:\quad1}{1}
                \gantttitlelist{2,...,24}{1} \\
                \ganttgroup{Work Package}{1}{24} \\
                \ganttgroup{Deliverable}{24}{24} \\
                \ganttgroup{Milestone}{5}{5} \\
                \ganttmilestone{Milestone 1}{16}\\
                \ganttgroup{Secondment}{20}{23} \\
                \ganttgroup{Short stay}{16}{16} \\
                \ganttgroup{Training}{5}{5} \\
                \ganttgroup{Dissemination}{23}{24} \\
                \ganttgroup{Communication}{12}{12} \\
                \ganttgroup{Other}{18}{21}\\
                \ganttmilestone{Milestone 2}{21}
            \end{ganttchart}                
        \end{center}
        \caption{Example Gantt Chart}
    \end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried that. However, this does not properly rescale. For example, if you have 
`\ganttmilestone` then those shapes were changed. I can have a workaround for that also using `xscale=, yscale=` but I was thinking if there is a better solution to handle the horizontal spaces.

Comment: Basically, my idea is to remove as much white spaces as possible between two black bars in the above picture.

Comment: @Boogeyman The limit is the font size. I also added  ``\ganttmilestone` and of course you have to change the form factors if you change only the `y` scale.

Comment: If you look carefully, there is a lot of white space between eg. the labels Others and Milestone 2 and their corresponding shapes. I wanted to reduce those.

Comment: I think it is related to reducing horizontal grid size ?

Comment: @Boogeyman The separation you saw is related to the "design" of the package. The group text is aligned with the horizontal bar, while in the milestone it is aligned with the center of the rhomboid. I made a correction to compensate the difference. Try the updated code with the milestones. A question not related: why are you using `\ganttgroup` instead of `groupbar` for  tasks?

Comment: @Boogeyman Normally you will have several tasks grouped. Then the group title will be slightly separated from the last task of a former group. See the example in page #49 of the manual.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzJO.jpg

Comment: I am using the bar as well and you are right that there I have handle to change the size of the bar.